# JSLint Shows so many errors but my program is working fine

Tags: jquery, jslint

I tried to validate my JQuery code from JSLint and getting lots of error. Please let me know how to fix.

This is a below Password Strength Meter code

```
    $.fn.passwordstrength = function(options){
                    return this.each(function(){
                    var that = this;that.opts = {};
                    that.opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.passwordstrength.defaults, options);

                    that.div = $(that.opts.targetDiv);
                    that.defaultClass = that.div.attr('class');

                    that.percents = (that.opts.classes.length) ? 100 / that.opts.classes.length : 100;

                    v = $(this)
                    .keyup(function(){
                    if(typeof el == "undefined")
                    this.el = $(this);
                    var s = getPasswordStrength(this.value);
                    var p = this.percents;
                    var t = Math.floor(s/p);
                    if(100 <= s)
                        t = this.opts.classes.length - 1;
                    this.div
                        .removeAttr('class')
                        .addClass( this.defaultClass )
                        .addClass( this.opts.classes[ t ] );

                })
            });

            function getPasswordStrength(H){
                var D=(H.length);
                if (D<4){ 
                    D=0;
                }
                if(D>5){
                    D=5;
                }
                // This is patern for non-numeric characters
                var F=H.replace(/[0-9]/g,"");
                var G=(H.length-F.length);
                if(G>3){
                    G=3;
                }
                // This is patern for uppercase and lowercase evaluation 
                var A=H.replace(/\W/g,"");
                var C=(H.length-A.length);
                if(C>3){
                    C=3;
                }

                var B=H.replace(/[A-Z]/g,"");
                var I=(H.length-B.length);
                if(I>3){
                    I=3;
                }

                // This is patern for Special Characters
                var P=H.replace(/^[@#$^&]*$/,"");
                var Q=(H.length-P.length);
                if(Q>3){
                    Q=3;
                }

                var E=((D*10)-20)+(G*10)+(C*15)+(I*10)+(Q*10);
                if(E<0){
                    E=0;
                }
                if(E>100){
                    E=100;
                }
                return E;
            }

            function randomPassword() {
                var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$_+";
                var size = 10;
                var i = 1;
                var ret = "";
                while (i <= size) {
                    $max = chars.length-1;
                    $num = Math.floor(Math.random()*$max);
                    $temp = chars.substr($num, 1);
                    ret += $temp;
                    i++;
                }
                return ret;
            }

        };

        $(document)
        .ready(function(){
            $('input[name="password"]').passwordstrength({targetDiv: '#pwd_strength',classes : Array('weak','medium','strong','complex')});

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your errors are style errors, JSLint doesn't like this:

```
if(condition) thing();
```

It wants to see `if()` with `{}`, like this:

```
if(condition) { thing(); }
```

To eliminate any ambiguity, like this:

```
if(condition)
thing();
otherThing();
```

`otherThing()` runs regardless of the condition, but that isn't clear at first glance, whereas this is:

```
if(condition) {
  thing();
}
otherThing();
```

---

Also it doesn't like optional semi-colons (and neither do I, use them damnit!), always include them, and this one's purely style: It wants to see the inner function `getPasswordStrength` declared at the top of it's parent.

Your program is fine and will run fine, you decide how much JSLint validation matters.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you write

```
if(typeof el == "undefined")
this.el = $(this);
```

It seems to me that

```
if(typeof el == "undefined") {
    this.el = $(this);
}
```

will be better to read (if it is what you want and you not forget something more). If you later decide use some minimization tools for your JavaScript code the usage of '{' and '}' can be very important to receive always correct working code.

Writing semicolons at the end of statements is good style in JavaScript, so why not to follow the recommendation and place after the next statement?

```
return this.each(function(){
   // ...
})
```

Moreover I find good to follow advices about global variables `$max`, `$num`, `$temp` inside of `randomPassword` function and add `var` declarations

```
var $max = chars.length-1;
var $num = Math.floor(Math.random()*$max);
var $temp = chars.substr($num, 1);
```

The same has sense also for `v` and `el` inside of `$.fn.passwordstrength` function. If you will use

```
var v = $(this)
```

or

```
$(this)
```

(because you don't use `v` in your code. It can be you wanted to use `this.v`, but you should know this better as me) instead of

```
v = $(this)
```

and

```
if(typeof this.el == "undefined") {
    this.el = $(this);
}
```

instead of

```
if(typeof el == "undefined") {
    this.el = $(this);
}
```

you program will work a little quickly and will have **less potential conflicts** because of the usage of the same global variables.

Removing unused function `randomPassword` can be also a good idea.

I find personally [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) very good because it helps to find some small errors which can be difficult found manually.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I need to edit my Regx and code for the Password atrength with below criteria.     1. Password has mix of letters and digits
   2. Password also mixes lower case and upper case letters
   3. Password has also at least 8 characters or more
   4. Password has also special chars like ?, *, \, " " or +
   5. Password has also at least 10 characters

Comment: @SASHI: Sorry Sashi, but how the `RegEx` is connected to the JSLint errors from your main question? The only JSLint warning is the recommendation to replace `/^[@#$^&]*$/` to `/^[@#$\^&]*$/`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "fixed" code. I removed the `randomPassword` function because it was not referenced in your code.

```
/*global $:false, document:false, el:true*/

$.fn.passwordstrength = function(options){
    function getPasswordStrength(H){
        var D=(H.length);
        if (D<4){ 
            D=0;
        }
        if(D>5){
            D=5;
        }
        // This is patern for non-numeric characters
        var F=H.replace(/[0-9]/g,"");
        var G=(H.length-F.length);
        if(G>3){
            G=3;
        }
        // This is patern for uppercase and lowercase evaluation 
        var A=H.replace(/\W/g,"");
        var C=(H.length-A.length);
        if(C>3){
            C=3;
        }

        var B=H.replace(/[A-Z]/g,"");
        var I=(H.length-B.length);
        if(I>3){
            I=3;
        }

        // This is patern for Special Characters
        var P=H.replace(/^[@#$\^&]*$/,"");
        var Q=(H.length-P.length);
        if(Q>3){
            Q=3;
        }

        var E=((D*10)-20)+(G*10)+(C*15)+(I*10)+(Q*10);
        if(E<0){
            E=0;
        }
        if(E>100){
            E=100;
        }
        return E;
    }

    return this.each(function(){
        var that = this;that.opts = {};
        that.opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.passwordstrength.defaults, options);

        that.div = $(that.opts.targetDiv);
        that.defaultClass = that.div.attr('class');

        that.percents = (that.opts.classes.length) ? 100 / that.opts.classes.length : 100;

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            if(typeof el == "undefined"){
                this.el = $(this);
            }
            var s = getPasswordStrength(this.value);
            var p = this.percents;
            var t = Math.floor(s/p);
            if(100 <= s){
                t = this.opts.classes.length - 1;
            }
            this.div
                .removeAttr('class')
                .addClass( this.defaultClass )
                .addClass( this.opts.classes[ t ] );

        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="password"]').passwordstrength({targetDiv: '#pwd_strength',classes : Array('weak','medium','strong','complex')});
});
```

Comment: @SASHI if my answer worked for you can you [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it?